# EntityManagerFactory: global or scoped instance when used in a Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, jpa

Considering a simple servlet app, I simply use a global(shared) `emf:EntityManagerFactory` instance which is initialized by `init():void` method by servlet instance load.
For each request I get a `em:EntityManager` from `emf`, use it, then close it(`em`).
I just realized `EntityManagerFactory` has got a `close()` method, so the question is, should I get a `EntityManagerFactory` for each request just as same as I do for `EntityManager`?
What is the best practice to use the `EntityManager`? is it okay to get -> do -> close for each request?

Comment: Look here i think there is your answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225638/how-frequently-should-i-create-an-entitymanager

Comment: Look here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862700/best-practice-to-get-entitymanagerfactory

Comment: If you intend to use the same `EntityManagerFactory` on different servlets of the same context, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22628862/how-to-share-entitymanagerfactory-in-jpa/22629592#22629592, which also answers your question.

Comment: @parsaporahmad Seriously consider using listeners as they seriously reduce coupling and help separate concerns.

Comment: @parsa porahmad think about more than one servlet, other wise you have to open and close it in each servelt, that will be so bad , open and close EMF in every servelt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should continue to use a single `EntityManagerFactory`. Call it's close method in your servlet's `destroy` method.

Comment: EntityManagerFactory are very expensive and heavyweight objects, they should be open on application start up time

Comment: That's what I just said

Comment: Thanks dude, I appreciate your help. It's cool when `user3...92`' comment is as same as your answer, haha haha.